# Add HTML code outside content area on every page load

Tags: hooks

I am trying to add HTML code outside the content area on every page load with the use of:

```
function us_page_build(&$page) {
  $page['content'][] = array(
    '#markup' => '<div class="fullscreen"><p>Here is my div content!!</p></div>',
  );
}
```

However, in this way I am placing the element within the content attribute. Is there a way to set it outside, having as parent only the html element? 
I am aware I can paste code into the template files, but then if I switch to another template(which I will) I will need to re-enter it.

Comment: put it to page.tpl.php ?

Comment: Thanks your the answer!Good idea, but in this way if I change theme I will need to re-insert it. I am trying to find a more generic way(sorry for not not being stated in the description above).

Comment: Yes, but if all your themes are custom, you can use base theme

Comment: Is there some reason a block won't work?

Comment: well no I figured out that the it is not really critical to have the element outside the content, at least for my purposes. I guess placing it in a block would take it outside the content at least. Well the main idea is to have an element whose parents do not restrict it's width and height so it can grasp the whole screen.

Comment: Regarding the base theme, wouldn't it be the case that if I change the base theme and then apply a new theme I should re-write the changes to the brand new theme I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content is a region in your theme. Site content goes into regions. So, typically you can only put things in defined regions such as Header, Footer, Left Sidebar, Content.

You have slight flexibility with `#prefix` and `#suffix` render array attributes. You either have to edit the html.tpl.php file, or define your own region within a theme. Or you can supply your own `hook_theme()` implementation to hint when using your own html.tpl.php template file.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) in your module:

```
function modulename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['page_top'] .= '<div class="fullscreen"><p>Here is my div content!!</p></div>';
}
```

Or your could set $vars['closure'] for Drupal 6 or $vars['page_bottom'] for Drupal 7.